# Calculate distance between two points in projection EPSG:900913

Tags: geometry, openlayers-2

I have two points in 900913 projection and I want to calculate the distance between the points.

I don't want to transform points to 4326 and then calculate.

How do I do this?

Comment: Why would you not want to convert to 4326? The inverse formula for 900913 (better called 3857 these days) is really very simple, see [inverse transforms on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection#Formulae_for_distance). After than you can use the Haversine formula. The whole lot could be done in a few lines of Javascript.

Comment: Openlayers Geometry has "distanceTo" function and I use it.

Comment: So what is your question then?

Comment: sorry I answer question later.

Answer (score 1):

You can't calculate distances accurately in 3857. (previously known as 900913 or 3785)

Well... *can't* is a strong word, so let's say that it's very difficult and there are easier/faster methods. The way web Mercator projection is designed makes it non-conformal; scale is a function of latitude.

To calculate distances accurately, you would first need to solve for map scale and direction. You can skip that headache and just convert to lat/long values and use a great circle distance formula instead.